# Javascript callback function not being called properly

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript callback function that is being called asynchronously, instead of waiting for a pending result.

```
 UploadMyScript.submitTitle = function(id, callback){
     // contacts webservice and returns $result
     createObject(id, $result);
 }
 function createObject(id, result){
     var filename = UploadMyScript._('paraHeading_'+id).innerHTML;
     var uniq_id = UploadMyScript._('paraHeading_'+id).dataset.uniq_id;
     var object = new UploadMyScript.title_fileName(result, filename, uniq_id);
 }
```

The submitTitle function is called from a click event:

```
subm_btn.addEventListener('click', function () { 
    UploadMyScript.submitTitle(this.id, createObject); 
});
```

I know that `$result` is being returned, but only after a delay. The callback function `createObject()` is called before the `$result` is being returned. I do not understand why this is the case.

Comment: Because you are not using promises. And how do you know the function is being called asynchronously? See this for example: https://gist.github.com/jeffcogswell/8257755

Comment: `// contacts webservice and returns $result` seems like it is an important part to the question. Can you post it, or give us some pseudo code?

Comment: i know the result is being returned through using console.log().

Comment: If the web service is called within `submitTitle`, then you need another callback that gets called to accept `$result` once it is ready (i.e. when the web service returns with the result).

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the callback, but the another function.

```
UploadMyScript.submitTitle = function(id, callback){
  callback(id, $result);
}
```

Comment: This is a good point, but they are still calling `createObject`, which is passed in as `callback`, inside `submitTitle`. So it's not the answer

Comment: // contacts webservice and returns $result seems to  be very important (because getting $result),  please add the code to your question